# Windows 10 BSOD after msconfig changes

Tags: windows-10, mbr

As a disclaimer I have read other posts and problems of windows 7, 8.1, and 10. None of them work... So, I have 16 gb of ddr3 ram in my motherboard. Windows only saw 8gb. I figured that windows didn't reserver 8gb for graphics cards and HIDs. I used msconfig.exe to allow "max ram"... long story short, now windows is stuck in a recovery mode loop. Safe mode doesn't work, and I tried chkdsk command numerous times. Also system restore doesnt work, and and system restore doesnt either. I would just like to know if anyone else came across this and how could I fix it? If any one need more information to help, just ask and I will edit my question to answer them. Thank you.

Comment: First off it is a BAD idea to got willy nilly messing with msconfig. That said, have you tried using an ESD (Emergency Service Disk?) on USB/DVD? If you have one or can get one try mounting the failing to boot install from that image and try to reverse your msconfig changes and reboot.  RE: the RAM, that could be a bad ram stick(s) or ram in excess of what the system board (motherboard) was designed to take, just because the board has 4 slots does not mean it can take 4X16gb if you understand.

Comment: I do understand, i consider myself a hardware person. I have been building computers for 5 years now. My motherboard the asus p5e3 standard supports the 16 gb of ddr3. Where can I obtain the ESD?

Comment: For a end to end tutorial and download links check this tenforums link out: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2570-esd-iso-create-bootable-iso-windows-10-esd-file.html

Comment: i got it fixed! i ended up using a windows 10 instaltion disk and running bcdedit /deletevalue {default} VALUE. replaceing value with the varible that was messed up.